# Android AlertDialog setMultiChoiceItems with custom background color

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I got this alertDialog with a multiple choice item selection:

```
builder.setTitle(R.string.layer_options_title)
    .setMultiChoiceItems(availableOptions, selectedLayerOptions, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        ...
    });
```

where

```
availableOptions = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.layer_options);
```

comes from

```
<string-array name="layer_options">
    <item>Should have green background</item>
    <item>Should have yellow background</item>
    <item>Should have orange background</item>
    <item>Should have blue background</item>
</string-array>
```

Is there any way to make these multiple choice items have a background color?

Comment: unfortunately not, no

Comment: Guys, did u check my solution? I was able to change background color of the check boxes inside AlertDialog. Was'nt it ur question? Please see the result picture.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. Put your checkbox in a layout and give the layout backgrond color. This is how I could do it:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LinearLayout mainLayout       = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout layout1       = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb1.setText("Easy");
        layout1.addView(cb1);
        layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        layout1.setMinimumHeight(50);

        LinearLayout layout2       = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout2.addView(new TextView(this));
        CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb2.setText("Normal");
        layout2.addView(cb2);
        layout2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        layout2.setMinimumHeight(50);

        LinearLayout layout3       = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb3.setText("Hard");
        layout3.addView(cb3);
        layout3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        layout3.setMinimumHeight(50);

        mainLayout.addView(layout1);
        mainLayout.addView(layout2);
        mainLayout.addView(layout3);
        alert.setTitle("Custom alert demo");
        alert.setView(mainLayout);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alert.show();
```

The result:

[image: The result]

Firstly, I created a main layout (vertical) as you see in the code. Then, for each one of the checkboxes I created a horizontal layout. In this case you can play with the colors and fonts of the elements (checkboxes, items, and etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder1.setTitle("Some Titel?");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            List<Spanned> listItems = new ArrayList<Spanned>();
            listItems.add(Html.fromHtml("ipohne"));
            listItems.add(Html.fromHtml("windows"));
            listItems.add(Html.fromHtml("<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>samsung</span>"));

            final CharSequence[] charSequenceItems = listItems.toArray(new CharSequence[listItems.size()]);
            builder1.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequenceItems, null, null);

            builder1.setPositiveButton("Weiter",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            builder1.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwuOH.png)

Comment: awesome! i have scoured on-line articles re this problem but imo this is the most efficient and elegant solution. now my next concern is how to convert android color codes to html. ha ha